# Cocos2D Sprites flickering on iPhone 6 and iPads

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I´ve created a game with Cocos2d which runs och looks great on my iPhone 5.

However, when running it on my iPhone 6, the animated sprites starts to flicker. This only happens to sprites that are moving.

I´ve searched around and found some fixes, none of them seem to work in my case. I´ve done this in the AppDelegate

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDepthTest:false];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
```

..and the flicker still remains.

All the sprites are loaded from the same sprite sheet so I don´t think it´s a performance issue.

I´m thinking this has something to do with cocos2d scaling upp my sprites to fit the larger screen, but I´m not sure how to get around it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Cocos2D?

Comment: Do an upgrade to v2.2. It may not fix that particular problem, but perhaps it does. More importantly v2.2 is compatible with 64-bit CPUs and Apple requires 64bit builds in newly submitted apps starting February next year.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for helping out, I'm actually doing an upgrade to V.3, have to do some refactoring but hopefully it will fix the problem.

Comment: upgrading to v3 is even better. ;)